# How can I time how long it takes a small block of C# code to execute?

Tags: c#, performance

I have this code:

```
  var userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  using (var context = new IdentityContext())
  {
      roleId = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT RoleId FROM AspNetUserRoles where UserId = " + userId).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Is there a very quick and simple way I could time how long this takes to execute. Even if the answer is put into a variable after this code block that would be enough as I can debug and see how long it took.

Comment: [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use stopwatch :

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

stopWatch.Start();

var userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  using (var context = new IdentityContext())
  {
      roleId = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT RoleId FROM AspNetUserRoles where UserId = " + userId).FirstOrDefault();
  }

stopWatch.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Comment: You're telling me that FirstOrDefault doesn't trigger the sql query @Avi?

Comment: you are right, it does trigger the query, i deleted my answer to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

u can put this code before the region:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
```

and this code after it:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = end - start;
```

and then in debug mode you can see the value of span;

Answer (score 1):

Stopwatch is your friend

```js
    // Create new stopwatch
     Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

     // Begin timing
     stopwatch.Start();

     // Do something
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(1);
     }

     // Stop timing
     stopwatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have four options, at least.

Small [test project](https://github.com/blfuentes/SpeedChecker) I did...

**DateTime Checker**

```
DateTime begin = DateTime.UtcNow;
//what you want to control...
DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine("DateTime.UtcNow measured time: {0} ms", (end - begin).TotalMilliseconds);
```

**Progress Checker**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

...

```
TimeSpan begin = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
//what you want to control...
TimeSpan end = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
Console.WriteLine("Process.TotalProcessor measured time: {0} ms", (end - begin).TotalMilliseconds);
```

**StopWatch Checker**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

...

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
//what you want to control...
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch measured time: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

**TickCounter Checker**

```
int start = Environment.TickCount;
//what you want to control...
int duration = Environment.TickCount - start;
Console.WriteLine("TickCount measured time: {0} ms", duration);
```